# How to Access Vuex Dynamic State Properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

How do I make *dynamic* properties added to Vuex state reactive? When calling any state property which has not been predefined, the result for both *getters* and *actions* returns `undefined` on refresh.

**Vuex Store**

```js
interface State {
    ...
    profile: { [key: string]: any }
}

export default createStore<State>({
    state: {
        ...
        profile: {},
    },
    getters: {
        name: state => state.profile.name
    },
    mutations: {
        mSetUserProfile: ( state, payload ) => {
            Object.assign(state.profile, payload),
        }
    },
    actions: {
        aSetUserProfile: ({ commit }) => {
            db.collection(foo)
                .doc(bar)
                .get()
                .then(response => commit('mSetUserProfile', response))
        },
        aGetName: ({state}) => state.profile.name
    }
})
```

**App.vue**

```js
setup(){
    ...
    store.dispatch('aSetUserProfile')

    store.dispatch('aGetName') // returns 'undefined'
    store.getters.name         // returns 'undefined'
    ...
}
```

Comment: what do you have in place of `// Dynamic Properties` and `aGetName: ({state}) => state.profile.name` looks useless

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I meant to add the mutation.

Answer (score 0):

`aGetName` is supposed to be a getter and not action.

`aSetUserProfile` contains a mistake, it doesn't allow inner promise to be chained, it should be:

```
    aSetUserProfile: ({ commit }) => {
        return db.collection(foo) ...
```

Actions are asynchronous, their result isn't supposed to be available immediately. They can be waited on component initialization by using `<suspense>`:

```
async setup() {
  await store.dispatch('aSetUserProfile')
  ...
```

Or this can be done after initialization in `onMounted`.